# undefined method `desc' for Sinatra::Application:Class

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake

This is the error I get when I run any `rake` command: `undefined method 'desc' for Sinatra::Application:Class`

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/contrib'

get '/' do
  puts "Hello World"
end

# config.ru
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application

# Rakefile
require './app'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'

# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'activerecord', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.4'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', '~> 1.2.3'
gem 'sinatra-contrib', '~> 1.4.2'
```

Full trace:

```
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:269:in `method_missing'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord/tasks.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:126:in `class_eval'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:126:in `block in new'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:118:in `initialize'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:118:in `new'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:118:in `new'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/namespace.rb:142:in `namespace'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1972:in `block (2 levels) in delegate'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord/tasks.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake.rb:77:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/j/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/j/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/backports-3.3.5/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/Users/j/Desktop/app/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/j/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Where does the backtrace point?

Comment: Added the backtrace and Gemfile.

Comment: and what's in ./app ?

Comment: see also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656858/undefined-method-namespace-for-mainobject-nomethoderror-active-record-r/66110634#66110634

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Sinatra namespace extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/namespace.html) from Sinatra contrib is interfering with Rake’s own namespace support. They both define a `namespace` method, and the Sinatra contrib version is being called (incorrectly) from the [Sinatra-ActiveRecord Rake tasks](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/blob/v1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord/tasks.rake#L3).

If you’re not using the namespaces from Sinatra-contrib, then the easiest solution would be to [only require those extensions that you need](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/#in-classic-style-applications); e.g. change

```
require 'sinatra/contrib'
```

to

```
require 'sinatra/whatever'
require 'sinatra/anotherextension'
```

If you are using Sinatra namespaces then I think you may be able to get round this by moving to a [modular style app](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra%3a%3aBase%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps). Change your `app.rb` to something like

```
require 'sinatra/base' # note this has changed from just 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/contrib'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Contrib

  get '/' do
    "Hello World"
  end

  # other routes etc. as needed
end
```

Then in your `config.ru` you need `run MyApp` rather then `run Sinatra::Application` (of course you can – and should – give your class a better name). This avoids the collision of the two `namespace` methods, since the Sinatra version is only available in your application class, not the top level.

Comment: I was running a modular app, but forgot the `sinatra/base` specific require. Thanks, saved me!

Answer (score 24):

Found an easiest solution:

Juste add the require:false attribute to sinatra contrib in your gemfile:

```
gem "sinatra-contrib",require: false
```

Found this here:

http://aaronlerch.github.io/blog/sinatra-bundler-and-the-global-namespace/

Comment: I am using Sinatra to mock an external API for tests in a Rails app, and had the same problem with `sinatra` and `sinatra-contrib` being required globally, by default, from my Gemfile.  This does fix it!  Thanks :)